# non-amenable subgroup of an amenable locally compact groups

Tags: topological-groups, amenability

I begin by recall this two know facts:

1- Every subgroup of a discrete amenable group is amenable

2-Every closed subgroup of a locally compact amenable group is amenable.

I need an example of an locally compact amenable group $G$ with a non-amenable subgroup $H$.

More precisely, i need an example to confirm that the hypothesis closed is crucial for the fact 2.

Thank for any help.

Comment: Chapter 0,1 of "Lecture on amenability by Volker Runde" has something about your question. I guess you can find your answer. I myself couldn't find your question's answer exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free group on two generators $\mathbb{F}_2$, which is non-amenable,  is a subgroup of $SO_3$ the group of rotations of $\mathbb{R}^3$, which is compact and thus amenable.

An interesting historical fact, I think that this was the example (used in the Banach-Tarski paradox) that motivated von Neumann to defined amenability and nonamenability.

Comment: Thank Owen. I miss this fact. I guess we can also the the orthogonal group O_{3} wich is also compact with product topology. Thank, thank, thank

Comment: @ Owen: I just wounder if the compact topology on the special orthogonal group $SO_{3}$ induced on the free group $F_2$ is the discrete topology. Because the free group $F_2$ is non-amenable in discrete topology. Thank.

Comment: Precisely this is not a discrete subgroup, so the induced topology on the subgroup isomorphic to $F_2$ is not discrete.